# WPF put one element one under another and then reorder

Tags: .net, wpf

How can I put one element under another and then reorder them (something like ZIndex)?

What I have done now is used Grid where two elements have same Grid.Column and Grid.Row but one of them is visible and other is not. The problem is that I need to make a "screenshot" of the control placed under another. But you can not do it if control's Visibility is Hidden.

So I need a way to place one control under another without using Visibility.

**Update.** About screenshot. I am making it by RenderTargetBitmap and it doesn't work if `controlToConvert` is Hidden.

Comment: "I need to make a "screenshot" of the control placed under another". Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Given that elements in XAML get layered on top of each other chronologically, couldn't you just write the element last that you want on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a canvas instead of a grid as the controls parent. Now you can reorder them by using the `Canvas.ZIndex` property, e.g. through `Canvas.SetZIndex();`

Answer (score 1):

Further to Florian Gl's answer, you can keep them in a `Grid` (or other layout panel) and use the `Panel.ZIndex` attached property instead.